# ¿como traer registros de una tabla bajo estas condiciones, con eloquent? laravel 8

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, join

tengo 2 tablas, `products` y `notifications`, en la tabla `notifications` hay una columna llamada **data**, donde guardo en formato json todos los datos de un producto y le agrego un campo llamado **type**.
ejemplo

```
{"id":2,"code":"12","name":"caja de bombones","due_date":"2021-11-04","type":"stock","days":"30","description":"qwqq"}
```

Con el siguiente código se verifica los id de productos que no estén en el campo **data**

```
Product::select('products.*', 'notifications.data->id AS jsonidproduct')
 ->leftJoin('notifications','products.id','=','notifications.data->id')
 ->whereNull('notifications.data->id')
 ->orderBy('products.id')
 ->get();
```

Pero ya no necesito consultar solo los productos que no estén en el campo **data**, necesito verificar que si no hay un registro con el id de un producto en el campo **data** me traiga la información de ese producto, pero que si hay un registro con el id de un producto en el campo **data** no sea con el type ='stock', básicamente es: si un producto no está registrado me traiga ese producto, si un producto está registrado en el campo data con el type = 'stock' que no traiga ese producto, pero si esta registrado con el type = 'fecha' o cualquier otro si lo traiga.

Intenté cambiando el whereNull por solo un where pero no sigue la lógica que necesito, no me trae nada

```
Product::select('products.*', 'notifications.data->id','notifications.data->type')
 ->leftJoin('notifications','products.id','=','notifications.data->id')
 ->where('notifications.data->type','!=','stock')
 ->orderBy('products.id')
 ->get();
```

Comment: con if else puedes solucionar tu problema, básicamente la lógica te está hablando en tu pregunta: if (product_does'n_exits){bring_product} elseif (type="stock"){return view()}elseif(type=="fecha" && type=="another"){bring_product}. Puedes llevar a cabo esa lógica en la vista directamente o en el controlador. No muestras modelos ni vistas por lo que es más difícil ayudarte.

Comment: @edwinboada es que no hay mas, lo que me traiga la consulta lo envio a una vista y ya, el modelo solo tienen todos los campos de la tabla products.